# How to link HTML::style to a separate static file server in laravel?

Tags: laravel

As the title implies, how can I link HTML::style to a separate static file server? Is there a global config file in laravel?

Comment: There's not a config option for this, but you can edit the method I'm sure.

Comment: No! Don't just edit the method. It belongs to the Laravel Core and should not be changed! You should either extend the HTML Facade or create your own Helper class

Answer (score -1):

This may not be the best solution but it should work.  Below is the method taken from `Illuminate\Html\HtmlBuilder.php`

The method name is `style` and it returns a link.  In the method you can change `$attributes['href']` to your URL and concatenate the asset's URI.

```
public function style($url, $attributes = array(), $secure = null)
{
    $defaults = array('media' => 'all', 'type' => 'text/css', 'rel' => 'stylesheet');

    $attributes = $attributes + $defaults;

    $attributes['href'] = $this->url->asset($url, $secure);

    return '<link'.$this->attributes($attributes).'>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

See the official API docs. here: http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Html/HtmlBuilder.html#method_style